# Arara rule to remove all files except 'tex' and 'pdf'

Tags: auxiliary-files, arara

I have this example

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: clean: { files: [test.log,test.aux] }
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section one}

\lipsum[1-5]

\section{Section two}

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

I want to remove all auxiliary files except `tex` and `pdf` files, with `% arara: clean: { files: [test.log,test.aux] }`  you can remove `log` and `aux` files, what  I need is also to remove all created `test.*` files leaving only `test.tex` and `test.pdf`

Rather then `% arara: clean: { files: [test.log,test.aux,test.toc,test.lof,test.lot,.....] }` is there a possibility to just only mention the remaining files in this case `test.tex` and `test.pdf`

Comment: Stupid question: Can't you just add the other files in the list?

Comment: You could make a new `clean` rule to use your own delete script instead of `rm` (which is what the default `clean` uses.)  But as @NicolaTalbot says in her comment, "delete all except" scripts are dangerous; I have a script `rmaux` which deletes all files with particular extensions. This is a safer way to proceed.

Comment: Could be quite dangerous to do that. What if you later decide to add an important file to that directory that doesn't have `.tex` or `.pdf` extension?

Comment: My folder contain only `test.tex` file and I want only `test.tex` and `test.pdf` in this folder after compilation

Comment: Hi Salim. Do you know how to do this with the current version (4.0) of Arara?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For arara 3.0 you could do:

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: lmkclean

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does it works also for Windows? I tried but I got this error: `Can't locate Digest/MD5.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Digest::MD5 module)`

Comment: @CarLaTeX No idea, I don't have windows.

Comment: @CarLaTeX The reason it doesn't work for you is that either you don't have a perl installation or you don't have the Digest::MD5 module. Download perl (e.g. ActivePerl, Strawberry Perl) and install the required module from its package manager. Perl usually comes with the Linux distributions, that's why user36296 did not have problems with it.

Comment: @ZoltánCsáti Thank you, I'll try!